# How do you set the ip address for Phonegap Developer app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm working with Phonegap Developer App to load my application on devices for testing.  When running phonegap serve in command line, I get the following:

[phonegap] starting app server...
[phonegap] listening on 192.168.1.210:3000
[phonegap]
[phonegap] ctrl-c to stop the server
[phonegap]

We are instructed to enter 192.168.1.210:3000 in the Phonegap Developer App in order to load the application on our different devices.

How can you customize the 192.168.1.210:3000 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Your LAN Card IP Address that created with a DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol).
You can configure it manually.
Go to "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections".
Follow the bellow Image.
[image: Select Your Connection]

[image: Select Internet Protocol Version 4]

[image: Set Your favorite IP Address]

Attention: **Your Internet Connection will be lost up to set your DNS and/or Default Gateway**

Comment: Note: you can not change the port **3000**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I have multiple addresses for various reasons and for phonegap to simply ping an address and call it good wasn't cutting it.

This isn't the most elegant solution, but it works as a fast hack.

Edit the file `<path to npm install>\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\lib\util\ip.js`

At the end of the file right before `callback(null, localAddress);`

Add `localAddress = '<yourip>';`

Hopefully they might add a command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have several network connections (maybe virtual one like VMWare). then go to Control panel/Network and Internet/Network connections and delete (or desable) all other connections.
it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** *This does not specifically address this issue but for those that end up here because the are having issues connecting to the app at the hosted address via the PhoneGap developer app, I thought it useful to provide the below information*

Because there are not a lot of SO questions relating to this, at least directly with viable solutions, to save others time since the issues are intertwined at the base level, the following is a good guide for resolving connection issues between the PhoneGap Desktop and PhoneGap developer app (found link via  [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/301#issuecomment-249656373)):

[PhoneGap Developer App is unable to download from the server](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/troubleshoot-faq/#phonegap-developer-app-is-unable-to-download-from-the-server)